# Linq where list contains one of list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have and array object that is a

```
List<ContactModel> contactList;

public class ContactModel
{
    public string CustomKey { get; set; }
    public string[] ContactGroups { get; set; }
}
```

So objects would be

```
{"1", {"Group A"} }
{"2", {"Group A", "Group B", "Group C"} }
{"3", {"Group C", "Group D"} }
{"4", {"Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D"} }
```

The ContactGroups contains a list of groups {"Group A", "Group B", "Group C","Group D"}
that a given contact exists in.
I can get results for one group by using the following.

```
var selectedContracts =
    from contact in contacts
    where contact.ContactGroups.Contains("Group A")
    select new { contact.CustomKey, contact.ContactGroups };
```

Is there a way to get a list back with all objects containing one of a list of objects.

```
var selectedContracts =
    from contact in contacts
    where contact.ContactGroups.Contains("Group A", "Group B")
    select new { contact.CustomKey, contact.ContactGroups };
```

I need to get back object 1,2,4.

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your post... look at the preview until it looks how *you'd* want it to look if you were going to answer. (Hint: half your code has too much indentation, and half of it has too little...)

Comment: `new[]{"Group A", "Group B"}.Any(x=>contact.ContactGroups.Contains(x))`

Comment: I am not able to understand what is your desired output. Can you update the result you are expecting based on input you have given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target method:

```
public static IEnumerable<ContactModel> SelectContacts(
        List<ContactModel> contacts, string[] targetGroups)
{
    return from contact in contacts
           where targetGroups.Any(targetGroup => 
                 contact.ContactGroups.Contains(targetGroup))
           select contact;
}
```

Examples of usage:

```
void Run()
{
    Initial();
    var selectedContacts = SelectContacts(contactList, 
      new[] { "Group A", "Group B" });
    PrintContacts(selectedContacts);
}
```

Help methods:

```
void Initial()
{
    contactList = new List<ContactModel>
    {
        new ContactModel
        {
            CustomKey = "1",
            ContactGroups = new[] { "Group A" }
        },
        new ContactModel
        {
            CustomKey = "2",
            ContactGroups = new[] { "Group A", "Group B", "Group C" }
        },
        new ContactModel
        {
            CustomKey = "3",
            ContactGroups = new[] { "Group C", "Group D" }
        },
        new ContactModel
        {
            CustomKey = "4",
            ContactGroups = new[] { "Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D" }
        },
    };
}

void PrintContacts(IEnumerable<ContactModel> contacts)
{
    foreach (var selectedContract in contacts)
        Console.WriteLine(selectedContract.CustomKey);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed. I wasn't quite understanding the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This returns 1, 2, and 4:

```
var objects = new string[]  { "Group A", "Group B" };

var selectedContacts = contactList.Where(contact => objects
    .Any(obj => contact.ContactGroups.Contains(obj)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for

Test :

```
    var contactList = new List<ContactModel> { new ContactModel {CustomKey = "1", ContactGroups = new[]{"Group A"} },
                                                new ContactModel {CustomKey ="2", ContactGroups = new[]{"Group A", "Group B", "Group C"} },
                                                new ContactModel {CustomKey ="3",ContactGroups = new[] {"Group C", "Group D"} },
                                                new ContactModel {CustomKey ="4", ContactGroups = new[]{"Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D"}},
                                                new ContactModel {CustomKey ="5", ContactGroups = new[]{"Group A", "Group C", "Group D"}},
                                                new ContactModel {CustomKey ="6", ContactGroups = new[]{ "Group D"}},
                                                new ContactModel {CustomKey ="7", ContactGroups = new[]{"Group C"}},};

    var CheckFor = new List<string>{"Group A", "Group B"};

    var selectedContracts =
    from contact in contactList
    where contact.ContactGroups.Any(x => CheckFor.Contains(x))
    select new { contact.CustomKey, contact.ContactGroups };
```